Custom Component breaks after upgrade to Joomla 5
I have a custom component on a site I just upgraded from Joomla 4.4.7 to 5.1.3 (in increments, not at once). The whole upgrade went well, and everything works except my custom dropdown field no longer displays. It defaults to a text field, which will not work for my use case. I thought perhaps the thing missing was a custom namespace. I had not included a namespace when my component ran on Joomla 3 and 4, though it worked perfectly. Yes, I did include the new import statement in the component model and view, and the import statement for the Joomla parent class in my custom field.
I wasn't sure what the value for the path attribute in the namespace tag below should be, since my component directory structure is still what it was in Joomla 4. The following does not seem to work.
<namespace path="components/com_accessm1/">MyEmployer\Component\AccessM1</namespace>

The actual file is at:
myappdirectory/components/com_accessm1/models/fields/titlelist.php

Import statement:
use MyEmployer\Component\AccessM1\TitlesList;

The object doesn't seem to get created at all because I logged some Info statements and they are not showing up in the Log file.
Is the path attribute value the problem?

Can you share the code for your custom field for those who might be able to help you. It may not have anything to do with your Namespace or path entries.

Clearly I have some error in my code. Embarrassing to admit, but I had forgotten to declare the namespace in my TitlesListField class file. However, I have the namespace declared in the custom field and the use statement where I'm using it.
Here is an example for another object. In my class I declare the namespace on the first line:
namespace MyCompany\Component\AccessM1;
In the file where I use it:
use MyCompany\Component\AccessM1\AccessMed1Helper;
The error I'm getting now is:
Class "MyCompany\Component\AccessM1\AccessMed1Helper" not found.
At least I've got info now.

\AccessM1\AccessMed1Helper - you need to be careful using capital letters in places other the first position of a file name or type as the Joomla core will convert to lowercase anything else and use that to search for the actual files. In the above the A for Access and H for Helper are fine but the M will be made lowercase and the file name it looks for will also a be a lowercase M. e.g. Accessmed1Helper.

Thanks, Irata. Looks like I have more tedious work to do in converting my component to Joomla 5.

From your directory structure it looks as if you haven't fully converted your component to use namespacing. This is a bit of a chore, but you do need to do it, and it will be better in the end! See https://manual.joomla.org/docs/general-concepts/namespaces/. The 'path' is just the folder below components/com_accessm1 where you store the directories of your class files. With a custom field you need to have an addfieldprefix attribute to tell Joomla where to find the class file for that field - see https://manual.joomla.org/docs/general-concepts/forms-fields/custom-fields-overview

Thanks, Robbie. I've actually been deep into that the last two days and am having success with it.
